# Understanding variables stored in dir()

Tags: python

From the python docs for [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> ```
> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope.
> With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.
> ```

My reading of that is it would do the same as `locals()` would, but that is wrong:

```
>>> dir()
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']

>>> locals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>}
```

What is the difference between these two built-ins, and why don't that provide the same result in this context?

Comment: `dir()` is a list of names, `globals()` is a dictionary mapping names to values

Comment: `dir() == list(locals())`

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` returns a **list** of names in the current local scope, as the doc says. On the other hand, [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) returns a **dictionary**. This dictionary has the names as keys and their values as values. The names should be the same as the list returned by `dir()`.